# Combining two API responses into one object without map/loop

Tags: json, rest, oop

I'm in a situation where I have to cover for poor API entity associations on the client:

Simplified example would be:

```
/api/cars

[
  {
    "carId": 1,
    "name": "BMW"
  },
  {
    "carId": 2,
    "name": "Citroen"
  }
]

/api/carcolors

[
  {
    "color": "blue",
    "carId": 1
  },
  {
    "color": "red",
    "carId": 2
  }
]
```

And I would need to get a data object like

```
class Car {
    String id;
    String name;
    String color;
}
```

Does anybody know a better way to handle this than calling /cars, which creates list of Car objects with color null, then doing request /carcolors, getting CarColor objects and then map/loop to put color to a car model.

Comment: If the API is set in stone, it seems reasonable that you need some loops to put the data together. Can you explain what your issue with this? A loop is a pretty fundamental construct so to help you it would help to know what your perceived problem is.

Comment: @Evert Problem is when it's a more complex object..

Expanding on my example, let's say I have /engines

which returns an Engine object like:

{
  horsepower: 400,
  car: {...} // parent car, that's now again missing that color attribute
}

Comment: Right, so you need a quick way to look up a color based on a car id. The answer below is good: Use a Map. Alternatively, you can use a regular object. Indexed by car id.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to loop, but you can avoid a *nested* loop with the use of a temporary `Map`, keyed by `carId`:

```js
let cars = [{"carId": 1,"name": "BMW"},{"carId": 2,"name": "Citroen"}]
let colors = [{"color": "blue","carId": 1},{"color": "red","carId": 2}]

let carmap = new Map(cars.map(car => [car.carId, {...car}]));
colors.forEach(color => Object.assign(carmap.get(color.carId), color));
let result = Array.from(carmap.values())

console.log(result);
```